# How can achieve different behavior for AJAX requests in Redirection Strategy of BjyAuthorize?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, acl, bjyauthorize

I've implemented my own RedirectionStrategy so i can redirect the user in the page i want. But in case that an AJAX post was made i want to return a JSON structure to client.

Answer (score 0):

One way to detect an AJAX request is to check the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header to see if it equals `xmlhttprequest`.

In ZF2 the `Request` object has a function `isXmlHttpRequest()` that does this check. Then once you've verified the request is from AJAX you can return a `JsonModel`.

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    return new JsonModel(array());
}
```